# Notify UITableViewController when cell is programmatically selected

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates

My table view allows multiple cell selection, where each cell sets itself as selected when a button inside the cell has been clicked (similar to what the gmail app does, see picture below). I am looking for a way to let the `UITableViewController` know that cells have been selected or deselected, in order to manually change the `UINavigationItem`. I was hoping there is a way to do this by using the delegate methods, but I cannot seem to find one. `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is handling clicks on the cell itself, and should not affect the cell's selected state.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most straight forward way to do this would be to create our own delegate `protocol` for your cell, that your `UITableViewController` would adopt.  When you dequeue your cell, you would also set a `delegate` property on the cell to the `UITableViewController` instance.  Then the cell can invoke the methods in your `protocol` to inform the `UITableViewController` of actions that are occurring and it can update other state as necessary.  Here's some example code to give the idea (note that I did not run this by the compiler, so there may be typos):

```
protocol ArticleCellDelegate {
    func articleCellDidBecomeSelected(articleCell: ArticleCell)
    func articleCellDidBecomeUnselected(articleCell: ArticleCell)
}

class ArticleCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBAction private func select(sender: AnyObject) {
        articleSelected = !articleSelected

        // Other work

        if articleSelected {
            delegate?.articleCellDidBecomeSelected(self)
        }
        else {
            delegate?.articleCellDidBecomeUnselected(self)
        }
    }

    var articleSelected = false
    weak var delegate: ArticleCellDelegate?
}

class ArticleTableViewController: UITableViewController, ArticleCellDelegate {
    func articleCellDidBecomeSelected(articleCell: ArticleCell) {
        // Update state as appropriate
    }

    func articleCellDidBecomeUnselected(articleCell: ArticleCell) {
        // Update state as appropriate
    }

    // Other methods ...

    override tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueCellWithIdentifier("ArticleCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ArticleCell
        cell.delegate = self

        // Other configuration

        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would have a function like 'cellButtomDidSelect' in the view controller and in 'cellForRowAtIndexPath', set target-action to the above mentioned function